# Getting dropdown selected cell reference in another sheet - NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I am using NPOI package in C#.
My excel document have 2 sheets.
First sheet has 3 dropdowns, second sheet has the sources for those dropdowns.
For each selected dropdown value, I need to get the address of the value in the second sheet.

I tried getting the reference using CellRefernce(ICell) but it's not working.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You need to add a minimal example that reproduces your problem or noone will be able to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.